# Script or Playbook to ADD Openstack neutron port add multiple IPs to an instance

Tags: python, ansible, openstack, openstack-neutron

Adding  multiple  ips to an openstack VMs either existing or new VM its horrible like am getting request to add more than 200 ips to an instance. How do i write a script or playbook ?

**starting IP from 192.168.0.50 to 192.168.0.150**

How i add multiple ips by manually here its

```
$ source Project_admin

$ openstack network list | grep Test12

| ID                             | Name  | Subnet           | ID |

| kshd332sjkh-kjhj-sdsds-sdsdsds |Test12 | (192.168.0.0/24) | derere43e-erere-drerer-erererer |

$ openstack port list | grep 192.168.0.49 # (it show the First NIC port information and Port ID of an Single VM its a primary NIC)
```

Here my first NIC port id is **3k3j43434-skdjk-erere-2323**

```
#openstck port set --fixed-ip subnet=**derere43e-erere-drerer-erererer**,ip-address=192.168.0.50 --fixed-ip subnet-derere43e-erere-drerer-erererer,ip-address=192.168.0.51 --fixed-ip subnet-derere43e-erere-drerer-erererer,ip-address=192.168.0.52 --fixed-ip subnet-derere43e-erere-drerer-erererer,ip-address=192.168.0.53    **3k3j43434-skdjk-erere-2323** **(myfirst-nic-port-id of 192.168.0.49)**
```

How do i perform this using **script/python** or playbook using **os_port** .is any way to achieve these would be more helpful my rotional task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OS are you on? If you have a shell like Bash at your disposal this would work for your specific example:

```
for octet in {50..150};do
openstack port set --fixed-ip subnet-derere43e-erere-drerer-erererer,ip-address=192.168.0.$octet
done
```

Comment: Thanks BakaKuna.. its worked. little changes as done to view ip ranges. Here my final code
 

**#!/bin/bash
for octet in {100..105};do
openstack port set --fixed-ip subnet=49ddsdsd0-llllc-47f1-aafewwa-2d472sdsewew,ip-address=192.168.0.$octet 4fsdsdsd-esds2-sdsdsb-8sdsd-8sdsdfsdfsdfs
echo $octet
octet=`expr $octet + 1`
done**